# How to add a new condition to access callback function in hook_menu_alter?

Tags: 7, hooks

I need to add a new condition to access callback function for a menu path.

For it I write hook_menu_alter and redefine there new access callback function.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items){
  $items[node/add']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_custom_callback'; 
}
```

And I have a question. I want this function to not overwrite previous access callback function, but add a new condition, which would be added to previous conditions for access callback.

How to do it most correctly ?

And is it possibly to do it not knowing the name of default access callback function ? For example, default access callback function for path node/add is _node_add_access().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call *default access callback* function in your *custom access callback* and if *default access callback* `return TRUE`, then you can check your own conditions and return TRUE/FALSE. Check example below:

```
function mymodule_custom_callback() {
  // If node access return TRUE.
  if (_node_add_access()) {
    // Do your processing here.
    if (condition) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

> And is it possibly to do it not knowing the name of default access
>   callback function ? For example, default access callback function for
>   path node/add is _node_add_access().

In such cases, you can either find it by debugging (`print $items['node/add']; exit;`) or you can append that as an access argument and call it from your custom callback. Something like below:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items){
  $items['node/add']['access arguments'][] = $items['node/add']['access callback'];
  $items['node/add']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_custom_callback'; 
}

function mymodule_custom_callback($function) {
  // If node access return TRUE.
  if (function_exists($function) && $function()) {
    // Do your processing here.
    if (condition) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: The OP expressly said _not knowing the name of the default access callback function_.

Comment: That is, to add my condition into access callback I can't do without information about default access function name ?
And I can't merely add my access callback function into some list, which would include all the access callback functions. And afterwarls they would be executed one by one when a user tried to go to that menu ?
path ? 

In my opinion, it's not not very convenient when developer has to search needed default function digging in the in the kernel of Drupal 7.
Although, of course, it would probably increase his skills.